# discord private message in embed form wont work

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots, discord.py

I want to make a command that sends a help embed to the user with .helpDM

AS you can see I tried this in event form.

```
@client.event                                              
async def on_message(helpDM):

    embed=discord.Embed(title='Hello',colour = discord.Colour.orange())

    embed.add_field(name='Bomb', value=f'Deletes Messages in chat\n .bomb 100', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Luck', value=f'Like 8ball fourtune teller', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Tof', value=f'True or False', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Hitme', value=f'See me holy face', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Monkey', value=f'Random pic of monkey monkey', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Whois', value=f'Userinfo', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='coin', value=f'Flips a coin', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Dice', value=f'Random number from 1 to 6', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Randomnumber', value=f'Gives you a random number from 1 to 100', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Meme', value=f'Random meme?', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Say', value=f'Says what ever you want the bot to say', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Kick', value=f'Kicks user (Needs Admin)', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Ban', value=f'Bans user (Needs Admin', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Unban', value=f'Revokes ban from user. (Needs Admin)', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Prefix', value=f'Changes prefix e.g .prefix !', inline=False)

    await client.send_message(embed=embed)
    # cllient.whisper wont work to
```

Command form:

```
@client.command()
async def helpDMM(ctx, member: discord.Member=None):

    embed=discord.Embed(title='Hello',colour = discord.Colour.orange())

    embed.add_field(name='Bomb', value=f'Deletes Messages in chat\n .bomb 100', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Luck', value=f'Like 8ball fourtune teller', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Tof', value=f'True or False', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Hitme', value=f'See me holy face', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Monkey', value=f'Random pic of monkey monkey', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Whois', value=f'Userinfo', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='coin', value=f'Flips a coin', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Dice', value=f'Random number from 1 to 6', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Randomnumber', value=f'Gives you a random number from 1 to 100', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Meme', value=f'Random meme?', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Say', value=f'Says what ever you want the bot to say', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Kick', value=f'Kicks user (Needs Admin)', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Ban', value=f'Bans user (Needs Admin', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Unban', value=f'Revokes ban from user. (Needs Admin)', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='Prefix', value=f'Changes prefix e.g .prefix !', inline=False)
    
    await client.whisper(embed=embed)
```

error,

await client.send_message(embed=embed)
AttributeError: 'Bot' object has no attribute 'send_message'

Note that, The Same thing goes for whisper...

Comment: `send_message()` is the old 1.0 discord.py method. You now have to use `send()`. This method still has the same arguments so you won't need to change `embed=embed`

Comment: I should check the documentation more, sorry, and thanks,

Comment: No problem, there's a lot of people that have similar problems here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With discord.py rewrite version you should use `<channel>.send()` instead of `<channel>.send_message()`

[reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=send#discord.abc.Messageable.send)